# Using BarChart and pastel colors is there a method to get the labels to be the same color as the bar?

Tags: graphics, color, labeling, charts

I am using version 8 and I have the following code:

```
totals4 = {{1093, "AUSTRALIA"}, {235, "BELGIUM"}, {474, "BERMUDA"}, {187, "BRAZIL"}};
BarChart[#, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
         ChartLabels -> (Placed[Rotate[Style[#, Blue], Pi/3] & /@ #2, {{.5, 0}, {1, 1}}])
         ] & @@ Transpose[totals4]
```

Is there a way to get the labels to be the same color as their respective bar?

Thank you in advance.

[image: bar chart]

Comment: Where is `totals4`?

Comment: totals4 has this data: {{1093, "AUSTRALIA"}, {235, "BELGIUM"}, {474, "BERMUDA"}, {187, 
  "BRAZIL"}}

Comment: At this point I'd like to register a small protest on behalf of people with less than perfect eyesight who will find rotated pastel-colored text difficult to read. Why not make the labels simple, straight, and readable, rather than 'interesting'?! OK, protest over... :)

Comment: If it helps, the chart will be going on a website with a gray background.

Comment: @sente Nooooooo!!!!!! :) well, ok, but run it through [the accessibility checker](http://www.accesskeys.org/tools/color-contrast.html) first. Or read [web pages that suck](http://www.webpagesthatsuck.com/biggest-mistakes-in-web-design-1995-2015.html)... :)

Comment: @cormullion, thanks for the second link; I'd seen it before, but forgot to bookmark it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess something like this:

```
BarChart[Range[4], ChartStyle -> "Pastel", ChartLabels ->
         MapIndexed[Style[#1, ColorData["Pastel", Rescale[#2[[1]], {1, 4}]], Bold, 16] &,
                    CharacterRange["A", "D"]]]
```

[image: bar chart with colored labels]

Since `ColorData["Pastel"]` only supports arguments in the interval $[0,1]$, a rescaling is necessary; ponder for instance on the result of `Rescale[Range[4], {1, 4}]`.

Comment: The name of the countries will change depending upon the query. Is it possible to not hard code it? In other words Australia is Purple and Belgium would be Orange and so on. If it is not possible with labels is it possible with legends?

Comment: Well, some legwork from you, first: did you already manage to produce a bar chart with the bars colored the way you want them? (That is, data for Australia is purple, etc.)

Comment: Well the query that generated the data was this one: totals4 = SQLExecute[conn, "
  SELECT t2.cnt, t2.description   
  FROM name_loc t1 
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT COUNT(*) 'cnt', f.fk_cnty_id 'fk_cnty_id', c.description \
'description'
      FROM name_loc          f
      INNER JOIN countries   c ON f.fk_cnty_id  = c.id  
        and c.letter_code <> 'US'
      INNER JOIN identifiers i ON f.fk_ident_id = i.id 
      GROUP BY f.fk_cnty_id
      HAVING COUNT(*)>100
  ) as t2
  ON  t1.fk_cnty_id = t2.fk_cnty_id 
   GROUP BY t1.fk_cnty_id       
    limit 4
  "]

Comment: The exact color for the country does not matter. Usually there are thirty countries in the chart, that is why hard coding it is not an option. Basically I want to take whatever color Mathematica assigns to a particular bar and then use the same color in the label. If this is possible it would be great.

Comment: Well, all you really need is the length of your list of countries, or whatever. At the bare minimum, you can do `With[{n = Length[countries]}, BarChart[data, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", ChartLabels -> MapIndexed[Style[#1, ColorData["Pastel", Rescale[#2[[1]], {1, n}]]] &, countries]]]`. I gather it was not immediately apparent to you that the `Range[4]` and `CharacterRange["A", "D"]` were *replaceable* with your data; you did after all not initially mention the data you're working with.

Comment: Yes, I am new to Mathematica. I used: With[{n = Length[Transpose[totals4][[2]]]}, 
 BarChart[Transpose[totals4][[1]], ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  ChartLabels -> 
   MapIndexed[
    Style[#1, ColorData["Pastel", Rescale[#2[[1]], {1, n}]]] &, 
    Transpose[totals4][[2]]]]]. The labels are the same color now which is good, however they need to be rotated. I tried to insert (Placed[Rotate but was unable to get it to work, perhaps as I was not sure where to place ending ) and ].

Comment: You can do `n = Length[totals4]` instead, since it seems the length of your countries and corresponding data are commensurate. If you need to separate out the pairs, instead of having to repeatedly call out `Transpose[]`, you can do things like `totals4[[All, 1]]`. You'll want to put the `Rotate[]` bits within `MapIndexed[]`, e.g. `Rotate[Style[#1, ColorData["Pastel", Rescale[#2[[1]], {1, 4}]], Bold, 16], Pi/3] &`. In *Mathematica*, dissection goes a long way...

Answer (score 1):

### For Version 7

In version 7 the underlying `Graphics` expression that is produced by `BarChart` is highly conducive to a post-processing approach.

- Each bar *and* label is contained in an expression that also includes style information.
- The label however has an additional `Style` wrapper to effectively reset the color.
- To style the bars and labels similarly we need only to remove this undesired re-styling.

This can be accomplished with the following replacement rule:

```
 Style[obj_, {GrayLevel[0]}] :> obj
```

Complete:

```
totals4 = {{1093, "AUSTRALIA"}, {235, "BELGIUM"}, {474, "BERMUDA"}, {187, "BRAZIL"}};

BarChart[#, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
    ChartLabels -> (Placed[Rotate[#, Pi/3] & /@ #2, {{.5, 0}, {1, 1}}])] & @@ 
  Transpose[totals4] /. Style[obj_, {GrayLevel[0]}] :> obj
```

[image]

The rule may need to be made more specific if you have other objects with an explicit style of `{GrayLevel[0]}` in the chart.  An example of a more restrictive pattern that *might* be needed is:

```
Text[Style[obj_, {GrayLevel[0]}], pos__] :> Text[obj, pos]
```

Comment: Maybe one could also suggest using a background that has better contrast with the pastels... Perhaps just use `Framed` on the labels and insert a background color there. Anyway, nice observation of the inner structure.

Comment: @Jens can you confirm that this works on versions other than 7?

Comment: Oh wait, it doesn't work on version 8. I forgot your version 7 comment... Maybe wrap the labels in `Tooltip` and use a pattern based on that. I may give it a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately, in version 8, the text labels are no longer grouped in the same list as the bar they belong to. So the solution by that new guy @0x4A4D may be the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also inject the labels with the same color as the associated bar using a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
ClearAll[ceFX]
ceFX[cedf_: "Rectangle", style_: (FontSize -> Scaled[.04])] := 
 ({ChartElementData[cedf][##], 
  Text[Style[#3[[1]], style], Offset[{0, -2}, {Mean[#[[1]]], 0}], {0, 1}, {1, 0}]} &)
```

**Examples:**

```
BarChart[# -> #2 & @@@ totals4, ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", ChartElementFunction -> ceFX[]]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[# -> #2 & @@@ totals4, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
 ChartElementFunction -> ceFX["GlassRectangle", Directive[Bold, Italic, FontSize -> 20, 
    FontFamily -> "Segoe Script"]]]
```

[image]